# didrecieveremotenotification(:) delegate method

Tags: ios

I have created .apns file for push notification and I am getting push notification on iOS simulator but when I am trying to call `didrecieveremotenotification(:)` delegate method nothing printed. My .apns file looks like this:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "title": "Push notification",
            "body": "This is push notification demo",
            "sound": "default"
        },
        "content-available": 1
    },
    "Simulator Target Bundle": "bundle identifier"
}
```

Comment: check push notification in provisioning and capability. later see how you registering lastly, check the .pem file and its credentials to access it.

Comment: Are you actually trying to call a method called `didrecieveremotenotification`? Because there is a spelling error and it is all lowercase. Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling explicitly `didrecieveremotenotification(:)` delegate method? basically this delegate will be called by the system when it receives notifications. For more info you can refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application